# How to limit or change the size of Azure BLOB container?

Tags: azure, blob, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Is there any way to change the size of an Azure blob container? For example, initially, I will set the limit to X. Then, using the Java SDK, I want to change that limit.

Is such an implementation possible? If not, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to set a quota for a blob container. It can grow up to the size of a storage account.

If it's possible, do take a look at Azure File Service. Equivalent to a blob container in blob storage is a share in file storage and you can define quota for a share. You can also change the quota of a share as well. The method you would want to use there is `setQuota` or `setQuotaWithResponse` available in [`ShareClient`](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/java/azure-storage-file-share/12.0.0/index.html).

Comment: Is there any way to emulate this  quota change in the storage level? Like, initially, the storage is X. If I uplaod some files and the storage gets full, then I can increase the storage limit to Y --- Is this scenario possible?

Comment: ^ Actually, this is the scenario I want to implement.

Comment: No. Storage account size is fixed (`2 PiB for US and Europe, and 500 TiB for all other regions (including the UK)1` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#storage-limits). You would need to implement your own solution.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean by "solution"? Like, limiting the filesize programmatically? (which means that there is no way to change storage account size or capacity?)

Comment: `Like, limiting the filesize programmatically?` - Yeah, more or less like it. `(which means that there is no way to change storage account size or capacity?)` - that's correct.